# Assistance with code to show my full webpage when i resize it to it's smallest width and/or making my webpage responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, web-frontend, responsiveness

I am currently working on my personal website, yet I am having trouble trying to get my code to work correctly.

I am going to post pictures to show what I am looking at [My website at the largest width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab9eG.png) and [My website at the smallest width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXYWi.png), and I will also add the [link to my website](https://princehimourself.github.io/kingdom/) and the [link to my GitHub code](https://github.com/PrinceHimourself/kingdom)

I am looking for information/code/anything that can point me in the right direction or help me get my website to be responsive to resizing

Here is the css code for my "< body >" and the "< div >" i want responsive (I am not sure if this is where i am supposed to be looking at either but i do know it all should be put in **@media only screen and (max-width:1000px){}**)

```
body{
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
            margin: 0;
}

.main-area{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the right direction. Just add a few more breakpoints.

```css
/* (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

/* (Large Phones, 768px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {...}

/* (Tablets, 992px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {...}

/*  ( laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

if not possible for all of them add at least one for mobile devices `(max-width: 768px)` and one for tablets.

`min-width` means you are designing mobile first and then going upwards to larger screens and `max-width` means you are designing desktop first and then breaking for smaller screens.

Then inside those breakpoints add rules for the elements.

Like for your `main-area` you can do it something like this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .main{
        height: "auto"
    }
    .main-area{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

it will make the main area look nicer for mobile devices. And like this change properties for all other necessary elements and make adjustment to make them look nicer for example  making the icons bit larger and adjusting the padding etc.